# Hidden entity classes after running ADO.NET DbContext Generator

Tags: ado.net, generator, dbcontext

I've used the DbContext Generator in my VB.NET application and the entity classes it generates (not the .tt files) are only visible if I select the 'Show All Files' option in the Solution Explorer.

Any reason why this is happening?  I've noticed if I create a c# project and do the same then they are visible within the .tt files.